# How can I obtain the time when a HTTPRequest is made?

Tags: java, servlets

In a Servlet, I'll like to obtain the datetime when a request is made.

I don't want to use Java's Date Class because it could not provide the accurate time.

Any help?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you think creating a Date would not be accurate?

Comment: you could use System.currentTimeMilis()... but even so, I don't understand: because it could not be the accurate time

Comment: Connect to a Network Time Server. Some example code here: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=java%20ntp%20client&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.apache.org%2Fnet%2Fexamples%2Fntp%2FNTPClient.java&ei=PDMFUIueG4myhAf_-YDFBw&usg=AFQjCNHeQ3oe8hIz7HT1BJeL_bJJVpQjQg&cad=rja New Date() would be much easier!

Comment: I don't want to create a Date because I'll like to obtain the exact moment when a request was sent by the client without force the client to sent that information in the request. If the request doesn't provide it, I don't manage how to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Use client's computer time. This will require the client to send his or her system time explicitly in the request parameters or in a custom header. Not to mention arbitrary computer in the Internet might have much more inaccurate time.
2. Use external time servers to fetch current time.
3. ...or just trust your server, if it uses [ntp](/questions/tagged/ntp), you are on the safe side.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would exist some kind of datetime in the request sent by the client. If it's not that way, I'll just trust my server, it's enough for me :)

Comment: @jspuchau: there is no standard HTTP header/mechanism storing request time.

Comment: could you provide an example code for what you're saying here please?